# Unable to tag SCM Maven Release Jenkins GitHUB

Tags: git, maven, jenkins, github

I am unable to generate using jenkins->maven-release->github

Jenkins Logs

```
[INFO] Executing: /bin/sh -c cd /home/jenkins/jenkins_slave/workspace/SANDBOX-APP.RELEASE/parent && git push ssh://git@github.com/sloopsight-com/sandbox.git master:master
[INFO] Working directory: /home/jenkins/jenkins_slave/workspace/SANDBOX-APP.RELEASE/parent
[INFO] Tagging release with the label NPR1-0.0.1...
[INFO] Executing: /bin/sh -c cd /home/jenkins/jenkins_slave/workspace/SANDBOX-APP.RELEASE && git tag -F /tmp/maven-scm-1217902233.commit NPR1-0.0.1
[INFO] Working directory: /home/jenkins/jenkins_slave/workspace/SANDBOX-APP.RELEASE
[INFO] Executing: /bin/sh -c cd /home/jenkins/jenkins_slave/workspace/SANDBOX-APP.RELEASE && git push **ssh://git@github.com/sloopsight-com** NPR1-0.0.1
[INFO] Working directory: /home/jenkins/jenkins_slave/workspace/SANDBOX-APP.RELEASE
[JENKINS] Archiving disabled
[JENKINS] Archiving disabled
[JENKINS] Archiving disabled
[JENKINS] Archiving disabled
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] sandbox ............................................ FAILURE [ 45.334 s]
[INFO] sandbox-ui ......................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] sandbox-app ........................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 46.521 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-11-06T21:32:37+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 25M/246M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.3.2:prepare (default-cli) on project sandbox-parent: Unable to tag SCM
[ERROR] Provider message:
[ERROR] The git-push command failed.
[ERROR] Command output:
[ERROR] ERROR: Repository not found.
[ERROR] fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Please make sure you have the correct access rights
[ERROR] and the repository exists.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

I am wondering why jenkins or maven release plugin change my git repo URL.
If you all can see in above logs
URL is *ssh://git@github.com/sloopsight-com/sandbox.git*
And it is pushing at *ssh://git@github.com/sloopsight-com*

**End up saying, please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.**
But it is actually pushing at wrong URL.

Please help me out...

## Release plugin

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <tagNameFormat>NPR1-@{project.version}</tagNameFormat>
                    <autoVersionSubmodules>true</autoVersionSubmodules>
                    <releaseProfiles>release</releaseProfiles>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

## SCM TAG

```
    <scm>
        <url>${GIT_URL}</url>
        <connection>scm:git:ssh://git@github.com/sloopsight-com/sandbox.git</connection>
        <developerConnection>scm:git:ssh://git@github.com/sloopsight-com/sandbox.git</developerConnection>
        <tag>HEAD</tag>
    </scm>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by moving parent pom to project root directory.